# How to get image path from the src folder in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, image, deployment

I have added a few images in `src/components/assets/media/images` folder but when I am deploying to the Vercel application I am not seeing those files as deployed. It is still showing old set of
files.

[image]

[image]

These images/png files are there in github and deployment is happening from the same location but I checked it's not there in deployment.

I don't understand how to get the path of these logos to be included in external json which is available in monngodb

I am thinking maybe those files are never used in the application that's why they are appearing in asset_manifest.json.

The existing files are appending a hash before the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build the project before deploying:

```
npm run build
```

If so, try a hard refresh after deploying.  The old images might be cached.

On a Mac using Google Chrome.... open the inspector, then hold the control key then click the reload button then select "Hard Refresh".  or just press Control + Command + R

If you want a button for testing,

Try the following:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

If you are using Typescript and get an error, add the following before it like this:

```
//@ts-ignore
window.location.reload(true);
```

You need true.   Without it, it's just a refresh.  The browser won't reload the cache from the server.